# MochaUI tutorial

Tags: jquery, ajax, user-interface, mootools, mocha.js

where can I find a good and complete tutorial for [MoachaUI](http://mochaui.org/)?

I know good CSS, basic JS too and ofcourse php!
but this UI stole my heart but I couldn't find
a good tutorial to learn it :(

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

As far as I'm aware there isn't one, if you're not counting what's available on mochaui.org.

I've been working on an application using it, and I can give some pointers:

1. The library is currently under pretty heavy development. There are parts of it that are clearly works-in-progress (like some of the plugins). That said, the basic functionality is solid and alot of fun to work with. check the github ([here](https://github.com/mui/mochaui)) pretty frequently if you're planning on using it.
2. If you're going to try to learn it just by working with the code, I'd recommend the 0.9.8 branch and including the separated source files (Core.js, Window.js, etc), and not the combined source. The code in the separated source files reflect more recent updates, and it's easier to figure out what's going on when they're split up.
3. Don't hesitate to make use of the MooTools class system to extend (with implement, append, or refactor -  depending on what you need to do and the mootools version you're using) the Window/Column/Panel objects if you're trying to get one of them to do something specific that you want, rather than wrestling with the library as-is or editing the source.
4. If you're not all that experienced with mootools but are looking to improve your knowledge, trying to learn the library just from working with the code can be difficult at times but also very rewarding. The library's source isn't all that big, relatively speaking. If you can figure out how the MUI class (in Core.js) and the Window class (in Window.js) work and how they relate to eachother, then the rest of the library is pretty easy to grasp.

Good luck!